# Jenkins is updating my applicationContext.xml file with it's system properties?

Tags: spring, ssl, jenkins, spring-security

This is pretty crazy...

I have an `applicationContext.xml`, that configures a bean using system properties.

In my case I am configuring a bean to inject values from a file or if not there look into the system.properties(I expect this only to happen at run time!)

i have:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="foo.foo.fooBarImpl">
  <property name="keyStoreFile" value="${javax.net.ssl.KeyStore}"/>
...
...
</bean>
```

So when my java application that uses this `applicationContext.xml`(resides inside the jar on the classpath) starts it will pull the `${javax.net.ssl.KeyStore}` from a properties file or if the properties file is not there, attempt to get it from the system properties.

What is happening that I cannot explain is..when jenkins pulls from the repository, and builds..
it is modifying my `applicationContext.xml`! and actually writing in what is present in the system properties..and saving it before buildling the .jar!  my jar now as hardcoded values in it of SSL information(like the password...)

```
  <bean id="myBean" class="foo.foo.fooBarImpl">
      <property name="keyStoreFile" value="/mympath/keystore.jks"/>
    ...
    ...
    </bean>
```

this above modified applicationContext.xml is now in my .jar!?

is there a setting in Spring, or Jenkins(maybe) to prevent my `applicationContext.xml` to be modified and resaved into the .jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Maven on your build?

Could be that maven resource filtering is taking in place.

Please try on pom.xml something like

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/applicationContext.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```